# how can I load ejs template for the client side?

Tags: javascript, webpack, ejs

I have outer ejs "I tried to put it inside views folder and src folder and import it inside index.js but still not working". I want to send data to the outer ejs, I tried to load the file with axios but still not working

I imported the ejs.min.js im my index.js frontend file then I faked the data I wanna render to print it inside the outer ejs file. and Im using webpack as a compiler

```
import axios from "axios";

import ejs from "../node_modules/ejs/ejs.min.js";
import confirmedData from ".././example-data/response.json";



// some vanilla js code in between 

const confirmationElements = confirmedData => {
  console.log("387", confirmedData);
  console.log("388", ejs);
  // axios.get("./confirmation.ejs").then(response => console.log(response));
  const html = ejs.render(
    `
<div>
    <p class="">
      <%= confirmedData.customerData.eMail %>
    </p>
</div>
`,
    { confirmedData: confirmedData }
  );

//here im trying to print what comes directly from confirmedData object inside the template later I wanna import the confirmation ejs file and print confirmationData inside.

  console.log(html);
  return html;
};
```

and Im getting this error in the console when I try to do this

> Uncaught TypeError: ejs:3
>       1| 
>       2|
>
> > > 3|       <%= confirmedData.customerData.eMail %>
> > >           4|
>
> Cannot read property 'eMail' of undefined
>       at eval (eval at compile (ejs.min.js:NaN), :11:53)
>       at returnedFn (ejs.min.js:1)
>       at Object.exports.render (ejs.min.js:1)
>       at confirmationElements (index.js:445)
>       at eval (index.js:452)
>       at Module../src/index.js (main.bundle.js:1677)
>       at **webpack_require** (main.bundle.js:724)
>       at fn (main.bundle.js:101)
>       at eval (index.js:1)
>       at Object.0 (main.bundle.js:1699)

and it is api response and I already made axios call response and I got success

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "confirmationResponse": {
    "customerData": {
      "name": { "prefix": "", "firstName": "test", "lastName": "test" },
      "phoneData": [0123456789],
      "eMail": "test@test.de",
      "address": {
        "streetNumber": "Donald Trump 10",
        "cityName": "NY",
        "postalCode": "12345",
        "countryName": "USA"
      }
   }
}
```

and Im getting this error in the terminal when I try to import the ejs file and render it.

> ERROR in ./src/confirmation.ejs 1:0 Module parse failed: Unexpected
>   token (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file
>   type.
>
> > |
> >
> > #### User Details
> >
> > |     @ ./src/index.js 16:0-46  @ multi ./src/index.js

Comment: Can you post code from your app.js?